# thinking of migrating to tfs 2012

Tags: sql-server-2008, visual-studio, tfs, tfs-migration

I am using tfs 2010 /sql server 2008 r2 with vs.net 2010 at the moment. Thinking of upgrading tfs to 2012. Has anyone tried this? is this relatively easy? Should I upgrade to vs.net 2012 too? does it still work with sql server 2008 r2?

Comment: This is a "do my research for me" question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

from [SQL Server Requirements for Team Foundation Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd631889.aspx)

> **Supported editions**
>
> - SQL Server 2008, R2 Express¹
> - SQL Server 2008, R2 Standard Edition¹
> - SQL Server 2008, R2 Enterprise Edition with SP 1 CU1 (Aug 25, 2011)²
> - SQL Server 2012, Express¹
> - SQL Server 2012, Standard Edition¹
> - SQL Server 2012, Enterprise Edition
>
> ¹ Limited or no SQL Server High Availability support.
>
> ² If you’re using SQL Server 2008, R2 Enterprise Edition you need to update to cumulative update package 1 for SQL Server 2008 R2 Service Pack 1 to address a SQL Server issue with table compression.

For [Visual Studio 2010 you'll need the GDR patch](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=29082) for compatibility.

The upgrade itself is fairly easy, and there's plenty of guides out there. [Enabling the new features](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff432837.aspx) which is really easy if you haven't customized your process templates and only use the scrum v1 template.  For automatically upgrading the other templates you need the upcoming patch which is still in testing (i'd almost recommend waiting for this to be released), or you can do it manually.

[Manual upgrades](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh500409.aspx) require lots of commandline and xml editing.